# I created a trigger to raise an error if the deleted row have the datefin field that didn't exceeded a year

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Here is my code:

```
create or replace trigger tr_interdit
before delete on reservation
for each row
DECLARE
    V_res_date RESERVATION.DATEFIN%type;
begin
    SELECT DATEFIN into V_res_date
    FROM reservation
    where DATEFIN = :old.DATEFIN;

    if V_res_date<add_months(V_res_date,-12)
        then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Date fin na pas depasse un ans');
    end if;

end tr_interdit;
/
```

But I'm getting this error when I delete a row from reservation after being deleted even though it should not be.

Here is the error:

> DELETE FROM "DANIEL"."RESERVATION" WHERE ROWID = 'AAAFCvAABAAALHhAAA'
>   AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3392006' and ( "NUMR" is null or "NUMR" is not null
>   ) ORA-04091: table DANIEL.RESERVATION is mutating, trigger/function
>   may not see it ORA-06512: at "DANIEL.TR_INTERDIT", line 4 ORA-04088:
>   error during execution of trigger 'DANIEL.TR_INTERDIT'

Comment: why you are selectring from table? there is changed value in `:new.datefin`

Comment: because i want to get the value of the selected row to be deleted

Comment: Your `IF` condition does not make sense. `V_res_date<add_months(V_res_date,-12)` will never be true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  how can i fix it

Answer (score 5):

No need for a SELECT, just access the old value directly.

Your condition `v_res_date < add_months(v_res_date,-12)` will never be true.

I assume you do not want to use `v_res_date` in the `add_months()` call, but compare the value of `:old.DATEFIN` with the "current date" - `sysdate`

```
create or replace trigger tr_interdit
before delete on reservation
for each row
begin
    if :old.DATEFIN < add_months(sysdate,-12)
        then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Date fin na pas depasse un ans');
    end if;

end tr_interdit;
/
```